# Phaser function Collide between a group and a sprite

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm starting in the development of game with Phaser 2 CE. I'm trying to create a game whose the goal is for the player to avoid cubes which are spreading. At the moment, I'm trying to detect the collision between the player and the spreading, but it doesn't work.

I use this line de code :

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(monSprite, ennemies, restartGame());
```

And according to tutos, it seems correct. However, when I put this line in my code, the game restart all of the time, it's boring

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800,600,Phaser.AUTO,'content',{preload: preload, create: 
create,update:update}); 

var counter = 0;
var text = 0;

function preload(){ 
        game.load.image('main_character','asset/main_character.png'); 
        game.load.image('ennemy','asset/ennemy.png'); 
} 
function create(){ 
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        //initialisation du compteur 
        counter = 0;
        text = 0;
        //add sprite ofe main character, position
        monSprite=game.add.sprite(0,0,'main_character');
        monSprite.anchor.setTo (0.5,0.5); 
        monSprite.x=400; 
        monSprite.y=300; 
        monSprite.angle=0
        game.physics.enable(monSprite,Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        //add sprite of main ennemy, position
        //ennemy = game.add.sprite(0,0,'ennemy');
        //variable qui compte le nombre de tour de la fonction update
        i = 0;
        //variable qui compte le nombre de vague de propagation
        i_spreading = 0;
        //groupe pour les ennemies
        //variable qui permet d'accélérer ou de ralentir la propagation
        a = 15;
        //variable qui correpond au nombre de boucle avant que la propagation s'arrete
        end_spreading = 100;
        //Text du temps
        text = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'Temps: 0', { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ffffff", align: "center" });
        text.anchor.setTo(-1, 7.5);
        game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND, updateCounter, this);
        // Create an empty group
        ennemies = game.add.group(); 
    }       
function update(){ 
        //vérifie si le joueur ne quitte pas le terrain
        exit();
        //Déplacement
        move();
        //variable qui vaut 0 si i/a n'a pas de reste
        tempo = i%a;
        //variable qui correpond au nombre de boucle avant que la propagation commence
        start_spreading = 10;
        //condition qui agit différemment en fonction du nombre de fois que la fonction update est appelée
        //apparition du première ennemie
        //compteur
        i = i +1;
        if(i == start_spreading){

            //game.physics.arcade.collide(monSprite, ennemies, restartGame());
            //position initiale de l'ennemie différente de celle du joueur
            do{
                x =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
                y =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
            }while(x != monSprite.x && y != monSprite.y);
            add_ennemy(x,y);
        }
        //propagation if(début de la propagation, fin de la propagation, tempo == 0 ne doit pas être changé)
        if(i>start_spreading && i<end_spreading && tempo == 0){
            //variable qui prendre des valeurs entre 0 et 3
            random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            //En fonction de la varaiable aléatoire on ajoute ou soutrait 10px 
            switch (random) {
              case 0:
                 x = x + 10;
                break;
              case 1:
                 x = x - 10; 
                break;
              case 2:
                 y = y -10;
                break;
              case 3:
                 y = y +10;
                break;
            }
        if(x>800 || x<0 || y<0 || y>600){
           ennemies.removeAll();
           i = 0;
        }
            add_ennemy(x,y);
        }
        //Si la propagation quitte le terrain on relance une nouvelle propagation
        //Si on arrive dans la dernière boucle alors on initialise le compteur i et incrémente le compteur de propagation et on le détruit
        if(i == (end_spreading-1)){
           ennemies.removeAll();
           i = 0;
           i_spreading = i_spreading + 1;
           end_spreading = end_spreading +100;
           if(a>2){
               a = a -1;
           }
        }
    game.physics.arcade.collide(monSprite, ennemies, restartGame());

}

function add_ennemy(x,y){
        ennemy = ennemies.create(x,y,'ennemy')
        game.physics.enable(ennemy,Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        // Add the pipe to our previously created group
        //ennemies.add(ennemy);
}

//function which allows to main character to move
function move(){
    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.D)==true || game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT)==true){
        monSprite.x=monSprite.x+2
        monSprite.angle=monSprite.angle=90
    }
    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.Q)==true || game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT)==true){
        monSprite.x=monSprite.x-2
        monSprite.angle=monSprite.angle=-90
    }
    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.S)==true || game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN)==true){
        monSprite.y=monSprite.y+2
        monSprite.angle=monSprite.angle=0
    }
    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.Z)==true || game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP)==true){
        monSprite.y=monSprite.y-2
        monSprite.angle=monSprite.angle=180
    }
}

//fonction qui relance le jeu si on quitte le fond de jeu
function exit(){
    if(monSprite.x < 0 || monSprite.x > 800 || monSprite.y < 0 || monSprite.y > 600){
        restartGame();
    }
}

//Fonction qui relance le jeu
function restartGame(){
        // Start the 'main' state, which restarts the game
        console.log('Restart');
        this.game.state.restart();
    }

//incrémente les secondes
function updateCounter() {

    counter++;

    text.setText('Temps: ' + counter);

}
```

Thus, I don't understand how I can use the function collide, and perhaps I have made mistakes in my code before, so it doesn't work. Here, the files of the games : https://github.com/Fatavis/game_summer_irobotechart

I hope that you will able to help me, and if you need more details or you have have questions, don't hesitate ^^

Thank you in advance

PS: I'm french therefore I'm sorry for the mistakes in my english

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in fact :

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(monSprite, ennemies, restartGame);
```

I don't need brackets.